# How to refer CSS in XSLT using relative path

Tags: html, css, xslt

Hi i am trying to refer CSS from my XSL 2.0 File .
My Code in 00BatchLevelStylesheet.xsl to refer css and JS as below but its not refer those files under ss and scripts folders . I am running a spring boot application. I am not getting any error but its not referring the css inside that folders . If i hardcode the path its applying the styles. What is the mistake i am doing .

Java Call

```
String xsl= "Main_Stylesheets\\00BatchLevelStylesheet.xsl";
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = 
TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new 
javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xsl));
transformer.transform (new 
javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource("sample.xml"), new 
javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
      (new FileOutputStream("sampleresult.html")));
```

Reference in XSL

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ss/jquery-ui_1-11-2.css"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps those links are relative to the XSLT stylesheet rather than the HTML page? You really haven't given enough information to solve this one - we need a lot more context. Are you running XSLT 1.0 in the browser, and how is the stylesheet being invoked?

Comment: Hi , Added some more more Context on  how i am calling XSL and trying to create HTML . I am using XSL 2.0.

Comment: OK, you're generating HTML. The problem lies with the HTML you are generating, and not with the XSLT code that you are using to generate it. Specifically, the relative URI from the HTML page to the CSS stylesheet is wrong. Perhaps the phrase "i am trying to refer CSS from my XSL 2.0 File" hints at your problem. The XSLT stylesheet doesn't refer to the CSS, it generates HTML which refers to the CSS.

Comment: Yes you are Correct . That was the issue.Thanks